# Rows excluding first one are checked by default when data pushed in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

When I am populating data in the table using bootstraptable, all rows except first row are getting checked by default.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="tableDivID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:95%">
            <div class="modal-content " style="margin-top: 20%;">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Caption</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body min-height-400">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div id="tableId" style="width: 100%"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function populateTableData(){
  var data= [];
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   var row = {'id': i, 'sectionCode': 'hello', 'headerName': 'header'+i, 'amount': '123,123'};
   data.push(row);
   }

var columns = [
        {field: 'id',checkbox: true},
        {field: 'sectionCode', title:'Section Code',visible: false},
        {field: 'headerName', title:'Header Name'},
        {field: 'amount', title:'Amount',width: '30%', align:'right'}];

$("#tableId").bootstrapTable('destroy');
    $("#tableId").bootstrapTable({
        height: 350,
        checkboxHeader: true,
        columns: columns ,
        data: data
    });
}
```

Output:

[image]

I don't want any rows to be selected when the data loads. (i.e. all rows to be unchecked)

If anyone has experienced this, please tell me how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function populateTableData(){
    var data= [];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        var row = {'checked': false, id: i, 'sectionCode': 'hello', 'headerName': 'header'+i, 'amount': '123,123'};
        data.push(row);
    }
}

var columns = [
    {field: 'id', title: 'ID'},
    {field: 'checked',checkbox: true},
    {field: 'sectionCode', title:'Section Code',visible: false},
    {field: 'headerName', title:'Header Name'},
    {field: 'amount', title:'Amount',width: '30%', align:'right'}
];
```

Try putting the id separately from the checkbox, because the first id is 0 it evaluates to false, and the checkbox is not checked, and the rest are checked because the integers (1,2,3...) are evaluating to true.

Comment: I really missed that thought!!  Thanks a lot. It worked.